# Recursive formula for an inverted binomial table

Tags: binomial-coefficients

This is an inverted binomial table:

$$
\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
&&&&&&1&&&&&&\\
&&&&&1&&1&&&&&\\
&&&&2&&1&&2&&&&\\
&&&6&&2&&2&&6&&\\
&&24&&6&&4&&6&&24&&\\
&120&&24&&12&&12&&24&&120\\
720&&120&&48&&36&&48&&120&&720
\end{array}
$$

Each element $(n,k)$ is $\dfrac{n!}{\dbinom{n}{k}}=(n-k)!k!$.

Can we prove $(n,k)=\dfrac{(n-1,k)(n-1,k-1)}{(n-2,k-1)}$?

Answer (score 1):

Writing in terms of factorials,
$$RHS=\frac{(n-1-k)!\,k!\,(n-k)!\,(k-1)!}{(n-1-k)!\,(k-1)!}=(n-k)!\,k!=LHS\ .$$

---

Alternatively, from the well known relation
$$k\binom nk=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$
we get
$$\frac{n!}{k\binom nk}=\frac{n!}{n\binom{n-1}{k-1}}\ ,$$
that is,
$$(n,k)=k(n-1,k-1)\ .$$
Hence
$$\frac{(n,k)}{(n-1,k-1)}=\frac{(n-1,k)}{(n-2,k-1)}$$
since each side equals $k$, and your identity follows immediately.